# Unpacking 4-byte unsigned integers from binary file gives struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

Tags: python, struct, unpack

This is a repeated question but I couldn't find answer

I am reading a binary file in following format (just showing one of the 3000 lines in hex format as shown in sublime text):

```
0009 7f71 0009 b87b 0009 f24b 000a 2ce2
```

I want to read it as tuple of 4-byte unsigned integers

```
if filename:
    with open(filename, mode='rb') as file:
        fileData = file.read()
        unsignedData = struct.unpack('I', fileData )
```

However I get following error for last line in above code:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Try using `struct.unpack('2I', fileData)`

Comment: @martineau How do I change the endianness between big and little endian ?

Comment: See the `struct` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Decoding a few integers

The [`io.RawIOBase.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read) will usually return a lot more than 4 bytes (it's limited by the system call and/or file size).

On the other hand, the buffer's size in bytes must match the size required by the format string to [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack).

The overall data structure of your file is not clear, but to, for example, read 4 unsigned 32-bit integers encoded in little-endian (data you provided), you should slice the buffer:

```
unsignedData = struct.unpack('4I', fileData[:16])
```

### Decoding a stream

In case you need to decode an arbitrarily long stream of integers from your file, there are a few options, depending on the expected data length.

#### Short stream

```
with open(filename, mode='rb') as fp:
    fileData = fp.read()
    n, r = divmod(len(fileData), struct.calcsize('I'))
    assert r == 0, "Data length not a multiple of int size"
    unsignedData = struct.unpack('I' * n, fileData)
```

#### Long stream

You could use [`struct.iter_unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.iter_unpack), but it probably makes more sense to keep the large int data in an [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array) or [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) anyway.

Here's an example for a NumPy array:

```
import numpy
data = numpy.fromfile(filename, dtype='uint32')
```

I'll leave the loading into Python's homogeneous data array as an exercise to the reader (hint: [`array.fromfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.fromfile)).

Comment: When I open the binary file in sublime text, it shows me multiple lines in format "0009 7f71 0009 b87b 0009 f24b 000a 2ce2". I think this line is numbers in hex format. There are 3000 such lines in the binary file. I want to just interpret the bytes in the file as 4-byte unsigned int and fill them inside a tuple

Comment: So you want to interpret the whole file as (a stream of) integers?

Comment: Yes. Stream of 4-byte unsigned integers

Comment: Ok, @nurabha, I've expanded my answer to include some stream decoding options.